# Copying files from Windows 8 to Ubuntu causes unknown network error

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, samba

I've set up a new home server (Ubuntu 14.04, AMD 64, 3GB RAM, etc.). I have permissions set up on my shared directories, but I'm having problems when copying some files to those directories.

I can create, modify, rename, delete, etc. files in those directories without any problems. I'm copying files from my new Windows 8.1 computer to the server. I can copy smaller files (text files, small PNG's, etc.), but larger files aren't working. I did go set the FileSizeLimitInBytes key under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters from its default value to 0x3b9aca00 (1,000,000,000) (commas added for visibility), which appears to be the largest value it will accept.

I'm unsure if the issue is Ubuntu related or Windows related.

I've tried the following:

1. Copying from the command line yields the message "An unexpected network error occurred" after about 1-2 minutes.
2. Copying from explorer: The copy dialog opens, shows "Calculating" and the progress bar sometimes advances, sometimes not, between 0-2%, but it always shows calculating, before finally displaying an error (0x8007003B): An unexpected network error occurred.
3. I've researched the error, and can't find any Windows 8 related info or fixes.
4. I've looked in/tailed the log files on the Ubuntu server, and nothing is out of ordinary. It doesn't log any errors related to these files.

The curious part is, after this error is raised, a file has been created on the destination directory on the server and shows the full size, but further examining properties, the size on disk is somewhere between 3-8 MB (it changes every time). The file is not corrupted, because I've installed the programs from it, and I've tried copying other files of other types. The same problems occur with them.

I've also looked at the active samba connections under Webmin, and it shows a "DENY_NONE" status next to the directories and "DENY_ALL" next to the files while they're actively trying to copy. There are no log errors/denials/etc. in the Samba log, however. The permissions are correct for those directories (user rwx, group rwx, other - / 775). ACL is installed and active.

I'm at a loss of what to do next. Obviously, without being able to copy files to the server, there's not much of a point. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

For those who land on this page for solution.

This happens with Windows Server 2012 R2 not just Windows 8.

Increasing SEND and RECEIVE buffer might fix the issue.

Add the following line in your smb.conf and restart the services.

```
socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
```

Another alternative is to  edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add

```
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 32768 131072
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 174760
```

Then run `sysctl -p` for the changes to  take  effect. But this only helps for smaller size files (100Mb). It gets transferred fast enough before it errors out. Large file transfer (above 1Gb) still fail. It might helpful for other applications though.